# How to do the checksum of files in aix, when sending files to sftp and alos downloding from sftp

Tags: shell, scripting, aix, checksum

** I have written a scripts to find files continuous in all folder and send files to sftp and similarly wise a versa.But Now is want to do checksum of file and ensure that file is transfer to sftp properly.I tried the cksum as my OS is AIX but unable to do verification of both files checksum.  **

````
   ```#!/bin/ksh

    /* FileList="/data1/RBIADF_SFTP/Outbound/logs/Filelist.lst"  */
    /* IniFile="/data1/RBIADF_SFTP/CommonFiles/inbound.ini"  */
   /* ProcessLog="/data1/RBIADF_SFTP/Outbound/logs/ProcessLogs.Log" */

    echo $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') ": Directory File Watcher Started..." >> $ProcessLog

    while [ 0 ]
    do

    Loop=0

    while IFS="," read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6
    do
    if [ $Loop != 0 ] 
    then 



     if [ "${f5}" != "NA" ];
      then

       IsFileFound=$(find "${f5}" \( ! -name $f6 -o -type f \) -prune -type f | wc -l)

       if [ $IsFileFound -ge 1 ];
        then

        echo $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') ": ##STRART TRANSACTION##" >> $ProcessLog

        echo $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') ": File Found Processing Started... " >>  $ProcessLog

        echo $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') ": Processing File type= $f1, local path=$f5, SFTP Path =$f4" >>  $ProcessLog

        ls -p $f5 | grep -v / >> $ProcessLog

            ls -p $f5 | grep -v /   > $FileList

        dirpath=$f5

        DIR_NAME=$(date '+%d%m%Y')

        sh PUTFILES.sh $f4 $f5

        sleep 5

        echo $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') ": File Get Completed." >> $ProcessLog

            Archive_FOLDER_COUNT=$(find "${f5}/archive/" \( ! -name 'archive' -o -type d \) -prune -type d | wc -l)

        echo $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') ": Local File Archive Started. Archive Path=$f5/archive/$DIR_NAME" >> $ProcessLog
        if [ $Archive_FOLDER_COUNT != '1' ]
        then
            mkdir $f5/archive/
        fi

        FOLDER_COUNT=$(find "${f5}/archive/$DIR_NAME" \( ! -name $DIR_NAME -o -type d \) -prune -type d | wc -l)

        if [ $FOLDER_COUNT != '1' ]
        then
            mkdir $f5/archive/$DIR_NAME
        fi

        while IFS="," read -r sf1
        do
                echo $dirpath/$sf1 $dirpath/archive/$DIR_NAME/

            mv $dirpath/"${sf1}" $dirpath/archive/$DIR_NAME/

        done <"$FileList"

        echo $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') ": Processing File type= $f1 Completed.." >> $ProcessLog

        echo $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') ": ##END TRANSACTION##" >> $ProcessLog

        fi

     fi 

    fi

    let "Loop=Loop+1"
    done <"$IniFile"

    done
    ```

    ```
    #####  PUTFILES.sh ####
    cd $2
    #!/bin/ksh
    HOST=dpcftpuat.hbctxdom.com
    PORT=22
    USER=rbisftp
    PASS_DIR="/home/oracle/autoscp/enc_pass_dir"
    export PASS_DIR
    PASSWORD=`cat $PASS_DIR/pass_dpcftpuat.hbctxdom.com.enc|openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:hdfc`

    export HOST PORT USER PASSWORD SOURCE_FILE TARGET_DIR
    ##- Call expect
    /usr/bin/expect<< EOF
    set timeout -1
    spawn /usr/bin/sftp $USER@$HOST
    expect "password:"
    send "$PASSWORD\r"
    expect "sftp>"
    send "cd $1/ \r"
    expect "sftp>"
    send "mput *.* \r"
    expect "sftp>"
    send "bye\r"
    EOF

    echo "SFTP DONE"
    exit
    ```
````

**I expect that the checksum is capture of file before transferring to sftp and checksum is done after transferring to sftp and same is return in log.****

Comment: This script is too big. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond: FYI you can put `[mcve]` in comments and it will automatically put the correct link.  Same with `[ask]`

Comment: please ask just the problem you have ?

Comment: Need to do checksum of file before sending to SFTP area and after SFTP area

Comment: Can any one help